# Can't Get the selected value of spinner from my custom listview adapter in xamarin. C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Xamarin Help .

Can't Get selected value for spinner in  my custom listview adapter.

MyListViewAdapter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Kites
{
public class AttendenceViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
{
    private List<string> mstudents;

    private Context mcontext;



    public AttendenceViewAdapter(Context context, List<string> stud)
    {
        mstudents = stud;
        mcontext = context;


    }
    public override int Count 
    {
        get 
        {
            return mstudents.Count;


        }
    }
    public override long GetItemId (int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override string this[int position] 
    {
        get 
        {
            return mstudents [position].ToString();


        }
    }



    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView,   ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) // otherwise create a new one
            view = LayoutInflater.From(mcontext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_attendence , null, false);
        // set view properties to reflect data for the given row
        TextView txtStudent = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textStudentNameTeacherAttendence);
        txtStudent.Text = mstudents[position];
        Spinner spinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.spinnerTeacherAttendence);



        var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource (mcontext, Resource.Array.attendence_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line);

        adapter.SetDropDownViewResource (Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);

        spinner.Focusable = false;
        spinner.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
        spinner.Clickable = true;

        spinner.ItemSelected += Spinner_ItemSelected;

        spinner.Adapter = adapter;
        var abcde = spinner.SelectedItemPosition;
        spinner.SetSelection (abcde);




        // return the view, populated with data, for display
        return view;
    }

    void Spinner_ItemSelected (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
        var abc = spinner.SelectedItemPosition;

        spinner.RequestFocusFromTouch ();
        spinner.SetSelection (abc);
    }



}
}
```

Main Activity.cs

```
ListView lsStu = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listStudentAttendence);
        AttendenceViewAdapter adapter = new AttendenceViewAdapter (this, mstudents);
lsStu.Adapter = adapter;


for(int i = 0; i < abc; i++)
            {

            View view = adapter.GetView(i, null, null);
            TextView txtStudentName = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textStudentNameTeacherAttendence);
            string txtSN = txtStudentName.Text;
            Spinner spinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.spinnerTeacherAttendence);

            var txtS = spinner.SelectedItem;
// I Cant Get The Selected Value Here. , I Am Getting the default Value not the selected value .do i do that

            string studentattendence = "insert into student_attendence values ('" + txtClassID.Text + "','" + txtClassName.Text + "','" + txtDate.Text + "','" + txtSN + "','" + txtS + "');";

                SqlCommand abcdedh = new SqlCommand (studentattendence, con);
                abcdedh.ExecuteNonQuery ();

                Toast.MakeText (this, "Attendence Saved", ToastLength.Short).Show();


            }
```

I get the default value at position 0 but not the value which i have selected.
when i place a breakpoint in mylistviewadapter i get the selected value position every time i select a new value but i am not getting it in the main activity please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: You call `adapter.GetView(i, null, null);` So the second parameter `convertView` is `null` which means, that you will inflate a new view.

This approach fails, because `GetView` is not meant to be called outside from the ListView or the view that is using the adapter. The second reason why this will fail is the mechanism called view reuse. If you have 100 items in your list there will be much less views created (only as much as can be shown son screen simultaneously plus a few more for smooth scrolling).

The approach you should use is:

**Create a class Attendence**, that contains the Name and all other values that you need.

```
public class Attendence
{
    public string ClassId { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Attendence { get; set; }
    //TODO: maybe some more
}
```

**Inherit from** `BaseAdapter<Attendence>`

If the values in your list item changes, write them back to the current student (e.g. in your `Spinner_ItemSelected`).

```
public class AttendenceViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<Attendence>
{
    private List<Attendence> mstudents;
    private Context mcontext;

    public AttendenceViewAdapter(Context context, List<Attendence> stud)
    {
        mstudents = stud;
        mcontext = context;
    }

    // ...

    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView,   ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        Spinner spinner;
        if (view == null){
            view = LayoutInflater.From(mcontext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_attendence , null, false);
            spinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.spinnerTeacherAttendence);
            var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource (mcontext, Resource.Array.attendence_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line);

            adapter.SetDropDownViewResource (Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);

            spinner.Focusable = false;
            spinner.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
            spinner.Clickable = true;

            spinner.ItemSelected += Spinner_ItemSelected;
            spinner.Adapter = adapter;
        }
        else {
            spinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.spinnerTeacherAttendence);
        }

        // set view properties to reflect data for the given row
        TextView txtStudent = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textStudentNameTeacherAttendence);
        txtStudent.Text = mstudents[position].StudentName;

        // TODO: use mstudents[position].Attendence here
        var abcde = spinner.SelectedItemPosition;
        spinner.SetSelection(abcde);
        spinner.Tag = position; // use this to know which student has been edited

        // return the view, populated with data, for display
        return view;
    }

    void Spinner_ItemSelected (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
        var abc = spinner.SelectedItemPosition;
        var position = (int)spinner.Tag;

        spinner.RequestFocusFromTouch ();
        spinner.SetSelection (abc);

        mstudents[position].Attendence = //TODO: selected value of the spinner;
    }
}
```

**In your `MainActivity`** you can iterate over the list of students, not over the views of the list.

```
// given: students is your list of Attendence   
foreach(Attendence attendence in students)
{
    string studentattendence = "insert into student_attendence values ('" + attendence.ClassId + "','" + attendence.ClassName + "','" + txtDate.Text + "','" + txtSN + "','" + attendence.Attendence + "');";

    SqlCommand abcdedh = new SqlCommand (studentattendence, con);
    abcdedh.ExecuteNonQuery ();

    Toast.MakeText (this, "Attendence Saved", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Comment: Hello Sven-Michael-Stübe. Actually i Can't Understand What you said. Can you please give me a example to do it. I get the Student Name. but i cant get the selected value by the user.

Comment: Updated my answer. There are some todos. Now it's your turn. Think about it and you will get the idea.

Comment: I am Doing as what you said but im not getting the value selected by each person but i get the value of the last spinner

Comment: Here is an example :) https://github.com/smstuebe/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/android-spinner-list/SpinnerList

Comment: i also need a same help like if i have a edittext Box instead of Spinner. so what will i do for getting a text.

Comment: You can do the same like with the spinner. `editText.TextChanged += ...`

Comment: Can you just Help me with it?.I got this. but one more solution needed for it.

Comment: Come on... you can do it. Just a tiny bit of thinking. Get the edittext, set the Tag to position, attach a `TextChanged` event handler and in the event handler, set the value of the item.

Comment: Ok Bro Got it. But i am getting a problem. When i select the item in my spinner. it dosent change the value in my list please help here. At mstudents[position].Attend = (string)spinner.Adapter.GetItem(abc); i get the value here on the right hand side but it dosent change in my list. please help with that.

Comment: Sorry. But i got the value. i found out my mistake now. Bro im glad that you helped me. thank's a lot. Stay Blessed